# HTML5 pattern validation being ignored

Tags: regex, html

I have an email input field that I have a regex of `^[^@]+@[^@.]+.[^@]+$`, but when ran it is not requiring the .com.

Go to https://jsfiddle.net/uscktx9d/ and type in www@www and hit submit. This should fail validation but is not. As you can see here https://regex101.com/r/pB6iF4/1, the regex should be requiring the .com.

Why is my HTML5 not requiring this?

Comment: You are missing the `\`` to escape the literal `.` in the question and in the linked fiddle. Adding the `\`` to the fiddle so the entire regex is `^[^@]+@[^@.]+\.[^@]+$` rejects `www@www` and accepts `www@www.com`.

Comment: and you can avoid first ^and last $ which are implicit in HTML5 patterns : [^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+ is enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're going to use HTML5 input validation for an email, use [type `email`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-type). This will do native HTML5 validation for emails and have added benefits (like showing an @ symbol on mobile devices' virtual keyboards).

Also, remember that any frontend validation should be re-validated in the backend.

To answer your question, though, you need to escape `.` with a backslash.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately the `type email` doesn't care about the .com either. The escaping is what I was missing though.

Comment: Maybe a good compromise would be `<input type="email" pattern="\.[^@]+$">`, the pattern would just check for a TLD and HTML5 would take care of the `@` logic.

Answer (score 1):

In a regex, a literal dot should be declared as an escaped `\.` symbol. See [Special characters in regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) that should be escaped if you want to make sure they are treated as literals.

Also, [HTML5 `pattern` attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-pattern-attribute) value is anchored by default, i.e. the whole pattern is wrapped into `^(?:` and `)$`.

> The regular expression language used for this attribute is the same as that used in JavaScript, except that the pattern attribute is matched against the entire value, not just any subset (somewhat as if it implied a `^(?:` at the start of the pattern and a `)$` at the end).

Thus, you just need to use

```
<input name="asdf" pattern="[^@]+@[^@.]+\.[^@]+" placeholder="email@example.com" title="email@example.com">
```

See [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qc9831fj/1/)